# Changing the action object's type in the reducer function

Tags: reactjs, redux

After processing the action that comes to the reducer function, i change the type of action according to the operation i do. Would it be a problem if we think that the reducer functions should be pure? To ensure that the reducer function does not grow, and that the incoming data makes the excess change on the state once.

a simple example showing what i mean:

```
const lineReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_LINE':
            action.type = 'INC';
            return [...state,action.payload];
        case 'UPDATE_LINE':
            return state.map(vehicle => vehicle);
        case 'TAKE_VEHICLE_IN_LINE':
            action.type = 'DEC';
            return state.filter(vehicle => vehicle.id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
const lineStatsReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INC':
            return state + 1;
        case 'DEC':
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
compineReducer({
    line: lineReducer,
    stats: lineStatsReducer
});
```

In this way, my component, which deals with the number of vehicles, is not rendered whenever vehicle data comes.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean?  That sounds rather odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, definitely **do not** mutate action objects like that.  It goes against the principle that reducers are supposed to be pure functions, and it's also going to make it a lot harder to trace how and why state is actually updating.

Instead, you should have both reducers listening to the same action type, and [independently updating their state appropriately in response](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action).  This is easier if [you model actions as "events" conceptually](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters).